# Searching for a string with Web.py

Tags: python, sql, web.py

I'm trying to build a python function with web.py and SQLite that will allow users to search for a given string within a description field and will return all matching results.

Right now I've gotten to the below function, which works but only if the input is an exact match.

```
def getItem(params, max_display):
    query_string = 'SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1=1'
    description = params['description']

    if params['description']:
        query_string = query_string + ' AND description LIKE $description'
result = query(query_string, {
    'description': params['description']
```

I've tried to implement this feature with `LIKE "%$description%"'` , however I keep getting the below web.py error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1245, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "lib/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 775, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "lib/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 2018, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "lib/web/httpserver.py", line 306, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, xstart_response)
  File "lib/web/httpserver.py", line 274, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "lib/web/application.py", line 279, in wsgi
    result = self.handle_with_processors()
  File "lib/web/application.py", line 249, in handle_with_processors
    return process(self.processors)
  File "lib/web/application.py", line 246, in process
    raise self.internalerror()
  File "lib/web/application.py", line 478, in internalerror
    return debugerror.debugerror()
  File "lib/web/debugerror.py", line 305, in debugerror
    return web._InternalError(djangoerror())
  File "lib/web/debugerror.py", line 290, in djangoerror
    djangoerror_r = Template(djangoerror_t, filename=__file__, filter=websafe)
  File "lib/web/template.py", line 846, in __init__
    code = self.compile_template(text, filename)
  File "lib/web/template.py", line 926, in compile_template
    ast = compiler.parse(code)
  File "/Users/sokeefe/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/compiler/transformer.py", line 51, in parse
    return Transformer().parsesuite(buf)
  File "/Users/sokeefe/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/compiler/transformer.py", line 128, in parsesuite
    return self.transform(parser.suite(text))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'suite'
```

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong with this function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Ahh.  I know.  What is your file name that contains that code?

Comment: The database code? It is product.db

Comment: No, your python code. I think you have a name clash somewhere.

Comment: The file is called sqlitedb.py. Interesting to think that it could be a naming clash...

Comment: For all the files you created, put `my` in front of their file names.

Comment: Did you name one of your files `parser.py`?

Comment: Yes I did, and renaming them with my in the front cleared the error I was getting. The search function still doesn't work... but at least that error is gone. What do you think is going on with parser.py?

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: *The search function still doesn't work*--Any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you think is going on with parser.py?

Here is the relevant portion of the error message:

> File
>   "/Users/sokeefe/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/compiler/transformer.py",
>   line 128, in parsesuite
>       return self.transform(**parser.suite**(text)) AttributeError: **'module' object has no attribute 'suite'**

So, somewhere there is a file called `parser.py`, which defines a function called `suite()`, which is used by some library code that executes when your program executes. But because you named one of your files parser.py, when the library code executes, python searches for a file named parser.py, and python found your file first, and there was no function named `suite()` in your file.